# App minimizing after load view controller on iOS 10

Tags: ios

On some devices with iOS 10, users reports that application goes into background after load some view controllers (different for each user).

There is no crash on device. If user double tap on Home button the application is present on multitask bar.

After tap on it is looks like func `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` is called.

Does anyone faces with similar issue?

Comment: That function is only called when the app starts, either after an install or after it was killed / crashed. If that function is running, your app is crashing

Comment: If the app crashes it will still be present in task switcher. It will simply start "from the begining" and not from the place in which it crashed. I had similar issue with an app and simply recompiling it with Xcode 8 solved the issue.

Comment: But there is no crashlog on device :/. I will try with xCode 8. Thanks for response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I did unwrap nil in one of my frameworks. Strange thing is that, iOS didn't report unwrapping nil object error, but send application to background without any kind of crash log.